# trying to fetch data that is available on specific node but not able to fetch data from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch data that is available on sector_10 node and want to display each node(data available in each node i.e Adress ,First_name,Phone_no) in recycler_view but I am not able to fetch data. I am using push() function to create new entry in my database.

[this is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQLKf.png)

Here is the code I am using,

```
for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
     getinfo info=new getinfo();
     info.setName(ds.child("maid").child("area").child("gurgaon").child("sector_10").child(uID).getValue(getinfo.class).getName());
     info.setAge(ds.child("maid").child("area").child("gurgaon").child("sector_10").child(uID).getValue(getinfo.class).getAge());
     info.setSex(ds.child("maid").child("area").child("gurgaon").child("sector_10").child(uID).getValue(getinfo.class).getSex());
```

By using this code I am able to fetch specific node that is available on sector_10.
this is my fetch_info java file

```
public fetch_info() {
}

public fetch_info(String first_Name, String adress, String phone_no) {
    First_Name = first_Name;
    Adress = adress;
    Phone_no = phone_no;
}

public String getFirst_Name() {
    return First_Name;
}

public void setFirst_Name(String first_Name) {
    First_Name = first_Name;
}

public String getAdress() {
    return Adress;
}

public void setAdress(String adress) {
    Adress = adress;
}

public String getPhone_no() {
    return Phone_no;
}

public void setPhone_no(String phone_no) {
    Phone_no = phone_no;
}
```

}

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all child nodes of `maid/area/gurgaon/sector_10`, use a combination of Firebase's listeners and `DataSnapshot`'s methods to loop over the data.

Something like:

```
DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

DatabaseReference sectorRef = root.child("maid/area/gurgaon/sector_10");

sectorRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(childSnapshot.getKey()); // -Lk4..., -Lk8...
            System.out.println(childSnapshot.child("Address").getValue(String.class)); // dghvbb, kjetr...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

The key differences:

- I use a much shorter syntax to get a reference to `sector_10`.
- I attach the listener much lower in the JSON tree, so that you retrieve less data.
- I use a loop over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` to iterate the dynamically generated child nodes of `sector_10`.

Comment: in verbose its saying :Cannot load key: Device key file not found.